# CSV export of a sharepoint list is including all items versions

Tags: sharepoint-list

I want to export a Sharepoint list by clicking on Export -> Export to CSV.

[image]

The list contains ~ 5000 items, but the export contains exactly 30000 items. The reason is that the export is including all versions of all items (30000 is the max number of items which is supported by the export).

I have already turned off the versioning in Settings -> versioning settings.
How can I turn off the versioning definitely? Thanks in advance.

[image]